# Using ArrayFormula to CONCATENATE string row by row

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that looks like the table below that is added to everytime a Google Form is submitted.

| TimeStamp | First Name | Last Name | Business Name | Formula |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/10/21 | John | Doe | Test Company | ==ArrayFormula(if(TimeStamp="","",CONCATENATE(FirstName," ",LastName," has just been hired at ",BusinessName))) |

The problem I'm running into is that the nameRanges are listing all entries at one time so instead of displaying...

"John Doe has just been hired at Test Company."

I get...

"First NameJohn Doe has just been hired at Business NameTest Company."

---

Is there a formula that would get each row checked individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recommendation**

You should put the cell range (e.g. A2:A, B2:B, C2:C) on your [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275), you may refer to this sample below:

**UPDATED**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="","",B2:B & " " & C2:C & " has just been hired at " & D2:D))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: The array formula doesn't seem to be auto-updating the collum rows as before. Did you manually pull the formula down? When using Google Forms to upload data to Google Sheets it doesn't allow any formulas to be overwritten in each row. I need it to auto-update unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, that's right. My apologies, I was not able to indicate it. I've updated the last part of my answer.

Comment: No need to apologize. I appreciate your time and help! Unfortunately, I need it to auto-update as before.

Comment: Thanks. Got you, I have updated my answer with a new formula. Turns out you just need to use ArrayFormula, IF Formula and the '&' operator to CONCATINATE the cells. This way, you won't need to drag the formula down anymore.